# Identify duplicate posts in Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Problem with identifying duplicate content on FB graph API.

If a photo album has been posted to the timeline more than once, the post is returned in the results multiple times with different `link`, `object_id` & `post_id` properties.

My code therefore can't tell that the number of likes is always `n (number of duplicates) * actual_like_count`.

How can I avoid counting twice?

EDIT: Here is some example data

```
type     status_type  link                 likes comments shares
photo    added_photos a.xxx.yyy.zzz/mmm    48    6        1
photo    ""           a.xxx.yyy.zzz/ppp    48    1        0
photo    added_photos a.xxx.yyy.zzz/ppp    48    1        19
```

In this example all the metrics are different, despite having the same album id (xxx).

Here is example of duplicate counts with exact same link structure

```
type     status_type  link                 likes comments shares
photo    added_photos a.xxx.yyy.zzz/qqq    63    3        0
photo    ""           a.xxx.yyy.zzz/rrr    63    3        0
photo    added_photos a.xxx.yyy.zzz/sss    63    3        0
```

Notice in the first table, the portion after slash in the link matches for the second two rows, yet still different metrics.

`object_id` is always different

Answer (score 0):

Albums posted to the timeline will have a post_id associated with it, which will always be different, but the link to the album remains the same. You can try comparing the Links for each album.

```
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=xxx&set=a.yyy.zzz.aaa&type=b&relevant_count=c
```

For the most part, the link will always be the same. From what I've seen, the `set` parameter in the link usually has a link to the album that would be the same for duplicate posts:

It usually looks something like:

```
set=a.xxx.yyy.zzz.zzz
```

The `a.xxx` is the album ID. You can check this by calling `/xxx` on the Graph API to get the album details.

Comment: Hi, I've added some example data above showing that the album ID being identical doesn't help. Sometimes, the numbers DON'T match :(

Comment: If you compare the entire link, it will be different, but if you just look at the `a.xxx`, it should always be the same for the same album. The other thing you can do is just look at `/me/albums` directly and use those metrics.

Comment: What I'm saying is that for a repeated a.xxx, sometimes the metrics do not match.